# Next.js static HTML export of fetched data

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I am building React app that will contain ratings of products, that will be fetched from BE. Rating of product will be then found on `/product/{id}`. Rating data of the product will be fetched from BE when the user loads page and then will be shown on the page.

What I want to achieve is to have these pages searchable by search engines by keywords that are fetched from the server. Is it possible to use Next.js with `next export` to generate static HTML and have these 'server data' already pre-fetched in the HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a research and yes, it's possible! At first, you have to define the paths  in `getStaticPaths` function of your page. Then, the server will pre-render those paths during the build.

In order to make server check for updates for new or existing pages, use `revalidate` attribute in object returned from `getStaticProps`.

More in the [Next.js docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#incremental-static-regeneration).